# #1093 - You can't specify target table 'new_keyword' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, sql-update

I have query like this

```
 update new_keyword set key_count=key_count-1  where  id in
    (select b.id  from new_keyword b ,new_news a ,new_mudoal_label c where c.label_id=b.id and a.id=c.id and c.type=1 and c.id=186)
```

The sub query return id for exmple (1,2,3)
but mysql show me error

Comment: are you trying to insert value taken from the same table?

Comment: Please also post the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with this code

```
update new_keyword set key_count=key_count-1  where  id in
    (select c.label_id  from new_news a ,new_mudoal_label c where  a.id=c.id and c.type=1 and c.id=186)
```